# Collision Detection between an instance in motion and array does not work?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2, collision-detection

I am trying to test the collisions between a bullet and an array of enemies in Actionscript 2.  However it is not sensing a collision.  This is the code in the bullet.

```
onClipEvent(load)
{
    facing = _root.player.facing;
    speed = 1;
    i = 0;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame)
{

if (this._name != "bullet")
{
    this._x += facing * speed;

    while (i < _root.enemyID)
    {


        if (Math.abs(this._x - _root.enemies[i]._x)<10)
        {
            trace("hit enemy");

        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest moving right along and looking at ActionScript 3. I then recommend using an open source physics library like Box2D to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` looks like it is being set to 0 only on load. So it will be checking all the enemies on the first frame, but since `i` will now always be greater than enemyID, it will never go into the loop again.

Try setting `i = 0;` just before the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.